# Android Facebook SDK Login Button Error exception

Tags: android, facebook, exception, android-activity, authentication

I keep getting an error when I insert the facebook Button into my login activity. MY login activity is a blank activity and it's corresponding file only contains the button which is ;

```
<com.facebook.widget.LoginButton
    android:id="@+id/authButton"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="128dp" />
```

My logcat reads;

```
07-31 06:34:26.773: E/AndroidRuntime(2006): FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #1
07-31 06:34:26.773: E/AndroidRuntime(2006): Process: com.example.mafta, PID: 2006
07-31 06:34:26.773: E/AndroidRuntime(2006): java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while      executing doInBackground() 07-31 06:34:26.773: E/AndroidRuntime(2006):at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:300) 07-31 06:34:26.773: E/AndroidRuntime(2006):    at    java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.finishCompletion(FutureTask.java:355) 07-31 06:34:26.773: E/AndroidRuntime(2006): at  java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:222)
```

07-31 06:34:26.773: E/AndroidRuntime(2006):  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:242) 07-31 06:34:26.773: E/AndroidRuntime(2006):     at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:231) 07-31 06:34:26.773: E/AndroidRuntime(2006):at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)07-31 06:34:26.773: E/AndroidRuntime(2006):at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587) 07-31 06:34:26.773: E/AndroidRuntime(2006):at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841) 07-31 06:34:26.773: E/AndroidRuntime(2006): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException 07-31 06:34:26.773: E/AndroidRuntime(2006): at java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap.containsKey(ConcurrentHashMap.java:911) 07-31 06:34:26.773: E/AndroidRuntime(2006):     at com.facebook.internal.Utility.queryAppSettings(Utility.java:391)
07-31 06:34:26.773: E/AndroidRuntime(2006):     at com.facebook.widget.LoginButton$1.doInBackground(LoginButton.java:676) 07-31 06:34:26.773: E/AndroidRuntime(2006):   at com.facebook.widget.LoginButton$1.doInBackground(LoginButton.java:1)
07-31 06:34:26.773: E/AndroidRuntime(2006):     at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:288)
07-31 06:34:26.773: E/AndroidRuntime(2006):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
07-31 06:34:26.773: E/AndroidRuntime(2006):     ... 4 more

whats the problem?
Thanks

Comment: please post the code of the your AsyncTask